# add additional value to the total

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to add the value from (discount) and (quantity) to my total. As for discount part, the customer will need to enter the right code to receiver discount. And for quantity, when clicked at the checkbox, then change the quantity, the total will also follow. Can you guys help me out on this problem? 
thanks
(sorry, my English is not good)

```js
function addItemPrice() {
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.myform.item.length; i++) {
    if (document.myform.item[i].checked) {
      total = (total + document.myform.item[i].value * 1); // another way to convert string to number
      count++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}


var sh_prices = new Array();
sh_prices["standard"] = 10;
sh_prices["express"] = 20;

function getAddShipping() {
  var shippingPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["myform"];
  var shipping = theForm.elements["shipping"]
  for (var i = 0; i < shipping.length; i++) {
    if (shipping[i].checked) {
      shippingPrice = sh_prices[shipping[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }
  return shippingPrice;
}

function getCode() {
  var theForm = document.forms["myform"];
  var discode = theForm.elements["discount"]
  if (discode == "UAC123") {
    alert("yes");
  } else {
    alert("no")
  }
}


function getTotal() {
  var totalPrice = getAddShipping() + addItemPrice();
  document.getElementById('Price').innerHTML = "the total price" + totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  Sickle $5 <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="5" onclick="getTotal(item)">
  <input type="number" name="quantity"><br> Sickle $1 <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1" onclick="getTotal(item)">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1"><br> Sickle $50 <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="50" onclick="getTotal(item)">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1"><br> Sickle $5 <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="5" onclick="getTotal(item)">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1"><br> Sickle $7 <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="7" onclick="getTotal(item)">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1"><br> Standard
  <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="standard" onClick="getTotal(shipping)" /> Express
  <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="express" onClick="getTotal(shipping)" /> <br> Discount code
  <input type="text" name="discount" size=15>
  <input type="button" id="code" value="check" onClick="getCode(code)">

  <div id="Price">
  </div>

</form>
```